# ListFragment onListItemClick not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, fragmenttransaction

I'm using tab layout with swipeable example, On of the tab is list view, and when clicked on list item new fragment opens up. My issue is when i click on list item, nothing is happening.
i'm using following example and adding my code  androidhive.info/category/tab-view

AddingList

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AddingList extends ListFragment {
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "List", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.pager, new List()).commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: is that load data to listView??

Comment: yes, listfragment with string of array does.

Comment: I mean is that load data to list and display in device?

Comment: @Merlevede - i'm sorry i'm new to android development. but i do "onListItemClick"

Comment: @anuruddhika - yes it does load list and display on device.

Comment: @Mihir I'm sorry, I didn't see the `onListItemClick` before. My bad!

Comment: i'm using following code and added my code to it .. http://www.androidhive.info/category/tab-view/

Comment: @Mihir Wait... Your `ListFragment` should have a `ListView` whose ID is equal to `android.R.id.list`... and You are saying that errors are coming. what are they? can you post logcat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code in onCreateView() method from onActivityCreated() method

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] values = new String[] { "List", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
    "Linux", "OS/2" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
 }
```

***UPDATE:***

```
  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


      FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.pager, new Home());
      ft.commit();

  }
```

Implement this method in your Fragment.

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

  // Make sure that we are currently visible
  if (this.isVisible()) {
    // Do your stuff here
    if (!isVisibleToUser) {
        Log.d("MyFragment", "Not visible");

    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: please take a look at the original question, i have added my updated code. i'm still running into some issue. when i click on list item, a blank fragment is coming up.

Comment: Just open toast in ListItemCLick

Comment: Huh? not sure what you meant. But i'm trying to open new fragment when list item is selected. Error is i'm getting blank fragment, and when i click on different tab program is crashing

Comment: @Mihir is your `ListView` id equal to `android.R.id.list`?

Comment: no ListView1.But this is what my xml file looks like, plus i don't see that i'm calling listview id anywhere in piyush code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Yes piyush, btw i have also added my AndroidManifest.xml not sure if anything is wrong in that.

Comment: There is wrong your ListView id must be android.R.id.list

Comment: where exactly is android.R.id.list?

Comment: In your xml file in which ur listview will be and u want to show data in it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pager1);

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                     //Your action


                }
            });
```

Comment: hello anuruddhika, thanks for helping me out. But i'm still running into some errors. can you please show me what would be final code look like?

Comment: now you can insert your action code inside the onitemclick method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . need to set adapter

```
        ListView mListContainer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pager1);


        //YOURADAPTER NAME
        mInformedListAdapter = new InformedListAdapter(mContext, mStatistics,this);

        //mStatistics is the my  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> mStatistics = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        mListContainer.setAdapter(mInformedListAdapter);
        mListContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

         //DO YOURS



            }
        });
```

Comment: can i use this code for listFragment? i'm still running into lots of error

Comment: please refer this :http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/handle-onlistitemclick-of-listfragment.html

Answer (score 0):

You guys have to call super.onItemClickListener method  in overrided method